# Card Game Name: 5 points and you’re out

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

I recently learned a new card game and the person didn’t know the name. Maybe someone else does. Goes like this...

A round begins with each player having been dealt 4 cards except the starting player is dealt 5. Cards are scored as face value except all face/ace/joker cards are 10 points. Each turn, you lay your highest card (ideally) and then draw from the deck or the top card off the discard. You can also lay multiples if they are the same number/face. Once someone reaches a card score of 14 points or lower, they can show their hand and play stops (or continue to attempt to get a lower hand). If they show and aren’t the lowest, they get a point against them. Otherwise, the person with the highest card score gets the point against them. A new round then starts with shuffled cards. Once anyone hits 5 points, they are out and rounds continue until only one person is left, the winner.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a variant of "Golf." I've played several (including Skyjo and Play Nine), but not this version. Most allow the player to at least see the top of the draw pile before deciding if they want to keep it (by discarding). It also sounds like "Silver" by Bezier games, but of course that doesn't use a standard deck of cards.

Answer (score 1):

Your game's type is [Draw and discard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Draw_and_discard_games).  Knowing the nationality of your teacher could narrow your search.  Your description sounds a lot like a variant of Yaniv / Jhyap.

Yaniv [description in Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/draw/yaniv.html):

> Deal: Five cards are dealt to each player

> The objective of the game is to have a lower total value of cards in your hand than the other players. When you think you have achieved this, you call "Jhyap" in Nepal or "Yaniv" in Israel to stop the play and compare hands.

> Each game is composed of rounds, and each player's total score is updated after each round. The goal of the game is to keep your score to a minimum. Players with more than an agreed maximum, for example 200 points, drop out of the game, which is then continued until there is only one player left.

Answer (score -1):

That card game is called 14.   ..

Comment: can you add a reference to the rules of the game 14?

Comment: In 14, the initial deal is 14 to each player with an extra card dealt to the player to the dealer's right. It differs in other ways as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatorze